# Reference a function to the data of a table

Tags: javascript, function, tabs

I have a table with code like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover bidasks">
        
        <tr>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askcount" dir="ltr">۲۲</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askvolume" dir="ltr">۸۲۱٬۱۴۶</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۳۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۴۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidvolume" dir="ltr">۳٬۴۸۲٬۶۰۱</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidcount" dir="ltr">۵۴</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askcount" dir="ltr">۲۱</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askvolume" dir="ltr">۲٬۰۳۲٬۶۴۳</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۲۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۵۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidvolume" dir="ltr">۵٬۲۰۷٬۴۱۷</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidcount" dir="ltr">۱۰۶</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askcount" dir="ltr">۳۸</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askvolume" dir="ltr">۱٬۱۴۰٬۵۲۹</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۱۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۶۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidvolume" dir="ltr">۸٬۳۰۱٬۹۳۸</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidcount" dir="ltr">۹۶</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askcount" dir="ltr">۱۳۷</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askvolume" dir="ltr">۴٬۴۶۶٬۷۰۰</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۰۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۷۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidvolume" dir="ltr">۵٬۷۱۷٬۸۵۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidcount" dir="ltr">۷۲</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askcount" dir="ltr">۱۱۵</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askvolume" dir="ltr">۵٬۵۴۸٬۴۱۹</span></td>
            <td class=" ask"><span class="askprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۰۹۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidprice" dir="ltr">۳٬۱۸۰</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidvolume" dir="ltr">۷٬۹۶۴٬۱۳۳</span></td>
            <td class=" bid"><span class="bidcount" dir="ltr">۸۹</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And I want to reference this function to give the number of columns and riffs by giving R and S values:

```
function m(r, c) {
return document.querySelector(".table").querySelectorAll("tr")[r].childNodes[c-1].span.innerText.replace(/,/g, "");}
```

But I do not know why my function does not work?
Friends, does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the span by querySelector as well:

```
document.querySelector(".table").querySelectorAll("tr")[r].childNodes[c].querySelector("span").innerText.replace(/,/g, "");
```

Comment: Thankful . I found another problem, we have to change the code `childNodes` by `querySelectorAll("td")`code. Anyway, thank you